# React three FBX to GLB very dark shader

Tags: reactjs, react-three-fiber, gltf, react-three-drei

I updated my code to load glb instead of fbx. Now my model is very dark.

The shaders are added programmatically. So they are the same.

It went from this: [image]

to this:

[image]

Here is my code:
App.js:

```
<Canvas
  camera={{
    position: [-7, 4, 7],
    fov: 40,
  }}
  style={{ width: "50vw", height: "100vh", marginLeft: "50vw" }}
>

  <ambientLight intensity={2} />
  <pointLight castShadow position={[40, 40, 40]} />
  <OrbitControls target={[0, 2.5, 0]} />
  <Suspense fallback={null}>
    <group
      rotation={[-Math.PI / 2, -0.15, Math.PI / 2]}
      position={[2, 3, 1]}
    >
      {Models.map((model) => (
        <Model
          key={model.id}
          path={"static/models/" + model.filename}
          scale={[10, 10, 10]}
          active={model.id === activeModel}
          envMap={envMap}
        />
      ))}
    </group>
  </Suspense>
</Canvas>
```

Model.js:

```
const Model = ({ path, scale, active, envMap }) => {
const textureLoader = new TextureLoader();
var textureBrushed = textureLoader.load(
  "static/models/textures/brushedMetal_5_bump.jpg"
);
textureBrushed.wrapS = RepeatWrapping;
textureBrushed.wrapT = RepeatWrapping;
textureBrushed.repeat.set(0.1, 10);

const matMetal_Copper_Brushed = new MeshStandardMaterial({
  color: 0xffcf46,
  roughness: 0.3,
  roughnessMap: textureBrushed,
  envMap: envMap,
  envMapIntensity: 1.0,
  metalness: 1.0,
});

const matMetal_Steel_Brushed = new MeshStandardMaterial({
  color: 0x8b7560,
  roughness: 0.2,
  envMap: envMap,
  envMapIntensity: 1.0,
  metalness: 1.0,
});

const ref = useRef();
const { scene } = useGLTF(path);

const { position } = useSpring({
  position: active ? [0, 0, 0] : [-10, 0, 0],
});

scene.traverse((mesh, i) => {
  if (mesh.isMesh) {
    if (mesh.material.name === "Copper") {
      mesh.material = matMetal_Copper_Brushed;
    } else if (mesh.material.name === "silver") {
      mesh.material = matMetal_Steel_Brushed;
    }
  }
});

return (
  <animated.primitive
    rotation={[-Math.PI / 2 - 0.15, 0, 0]}
    object={scene}
    dispose={null}
    ref={ref}
    scale={scale}
    position={position}
  />
);
};
```

What could be the reason? First thaught was a color managment issue. But when I set it to linear its even darker.

Answer (score 0):

THREE.FBXLoader uses THREE.MeshLambertMaterial and THREE.MeshPhongMaterial, and it will be very difficult to get an exact match without using those materials here.

You may also need to set `texture.flipY = false` as discussed in the [GLTFLoader docs](https://threejs.org/docs/?q=gltflo#examples/en/loaders/GLTFLoader) to follow the glTF UV coordinate convention, and `texture.colorSpace = THREE.NoColorSpace` for your non-color roughness. I am a bit surprised that a texture named `brushedMetal_5_bump.jpg` would be a roughness map rather than a bump map, but couldn't say for sure without looking at the texture.

Comment: Your right... the bump texture is mapped in the wrong channel, but thats not important here. There are no phongs or lamberts used in the scene. Just MeshStandardMaterials. I overwrite them in my traverse function.